# How to use array.map with tuples in typescript?

Tags: typescript, tuples

Whenever I use `array.map` on a tuple, Typescript infers it as a generic array. For instance, here are some pieces of a simple 3x3 sudoku game:

```js
const _ = ' ' // a "Blank"

type Blank = typeof _

type Cell = number | Blank

type Three = [Cell, Cell, Cell]

type Board = [Three, Three, Three]

const initialBoard: Board = [
    [_, 1, 3],
    [3, _, 1],
    [1, _, _],
]

// Adds a `2` to the first cell on the first row
function applyMove(board: Board): Board {
    // errors here
    const newBoard: Board =  board.map((row: Three, index: number) => {
        if (index === 0) return <Three> [2, 1, 3]
        return <Three> row
    })
    return newBoard
}

function applyMoveToRow(row: Three): Three {
    // return [2, 1, 3] // This works
    const newRow: Three = [
        2,
        ...row.slice(1, 3)
    ]
    return newRow
}
```

The TS error is:

```
Type '[Cell, Cell, Cell][]' is missing the following properties from type 
 '[[Cell, Cell, Cell], [Cell, Cell, Cell], [Cell, Cell, Cell]]': 0, 1, 2 .
```

[here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+jAvDA5KmB6DMCGMBEAQgDY5gDW+AsAFC1QCeADgKYwlnlIyOsgBm8WvWZsAwi2LFuYAK4BbAEYsATjAA+7UhWE1ebACoALFSzbIA2hKkAaGNeJ2HAXV372IHCoAm3C8dMWOwCzYJMzVzoaUEhYAEswOKg4nGJCTx8ALg8vX0taGEKYCzg7AEY7AGZnGwKii0q7UpgymrrCiwr4JraaSNosGABBb28IXBgAAwAmSZ4QHiM2fjiVaBhgSWlwReXV9ZUQAHdaflkwYGSdnCYmYgYAWRAANxYACkUM72z03IBKH5fGAAb3aG3A6zALCOvyyOR83Bgn1yADp5Dc3m9DkdsiEgjAEt4WAAPbJyJSqP5IAB8ILBRQJgjehJJSEQyAADFTTFBZCowDAADx42kWablKqRBkMnl8gXC8IsWnYsEAXz+YNl-JgUJhX1oqt0ZwuVwFNzujxeLAMIAASscscdcYqATA8XSaAzBlqBWKJTBqphsMY4uMjiAVOQIGCYpDofacW7FX56UVxanCiis9iURBiHFNm8upUNZ6ilKij6dfHjgagA) it is in a TS Playground.

Is there any way to tell typescript that, when I'm mapping over a tuple, it's going to return a tuple of the same kind, instead of just an array? I've tried being very explicit, annotating all of my return values, etc, but it's not doing the trick.

There's a discussion on the Typescript github about this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11312

But I haven't been able to get a solution out of it.

Comment: Are you asking about your `slice()` problem too?

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? It appears as though it was fixed in 3.4...

Comment: Of course, the easiest way of solving this is to just add ` as Board` after the `map`. And ` as Three` after the `]` for the `slice()` problem...

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah, `as Board` does do the trick, but feels like a "patch". Also, the playground is in TS 3.5, and still showing the errors there.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that... Might be worth raising an issue on their GitHub. Might be a regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind tweaking the way you assign `initialBoard` you can change your `Board` definition to this:

```
interface Board  {
    [0]: Three,
    [1]: Three,
    [2]: Three,
    map(mapFunction: (row: Three, index: number, array: Board) => Three): Board;
}
```

This is how you have to change the way you assign a literal to a `Board`:

```
const initialBoard: Board = <Board><any>[
    [_, 1, 3],
    [3, _, 1],
    [1, _, _],
]
```

Comment: This is great, I didn't realize you could add numbered keys to interfaces like this. Could you explain why the initialBoard declaration needs the additional `<Board><any>`?

Comment: because `Board` is no longer declared as an array, so you can't just assign an array to your `Board` variable without casting.  And if you just use `<Board>` you'll get an error about a possibly invalid cast that basically says "if you really know what you are doing, then first cast it to any, then to Board".

Answer (score 21):

TypeScript does not attempt to preserve tuple length upon calling `map()`.  This feature was requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#11312](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11312), implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#11252](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11252), and reverted in [microsoft/TypeScript#16223](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/16223) due to problems it caused with real world code.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#29841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29841) for details.

But if you want, you could [merge in your own declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) for the signature of `Array.prototype.map()`, to account for the fact that it preserves the length of tuples.   Here's one way to do it:

```
interface Array<T> {
  map<U>(
    callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U,
    thisArg?: any
  ): { [K in keyof this]: U };
}
```

This uses [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) types as well as [array/tuple mapped types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to represent the transformation.

Then your code could be written like the following:

```
function applyMove(board: Board): Board {
  return board.map(
    (row: Three, index: number) => (index === 0 ? applyMoveToRow(row) : row)
  );
}

function applyMoveToRow(row: Three): Three {
  return [2, row[1], row[2]];
}
```

and there'd be no error.  Note that I didn't bother trying to deal with `Array.prototype.slice()`.  It would be a large amount of effort to try to represent what `slice()` does to a tuple type, especially since there's no real support for [tuple length manipulation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223)... meaning you might need a bunch of overload signatures or other type trickery to get it done.  If you're only going to use `slice()` for short arrays, you might as well just use index access like I did above with `[2, row[1], row[2]]` which the compiler *does* understand.

Or if you're going to use it for longer arrays but a small number of times in your code, you might just want to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you know what you're doing.  For that matter, if you're only doing `map()` a small number of times, you can use a type assertion here too instead of the above redeclaration of `map()`'s signature:

```
function applyMove(board: Board): Board {
  return board.map(
    (row: Three, index: number) => (index === 0 ? applyMoveToRow(row) : row)
  ) as Board; // assert here instead of redeclaring `map()` method signature
}
```

Either way works... type assertions are less type safe but more straightforward, while the declaration merge is safer but more complicated.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+jAvDARKg3DA9FmBDVAIQBs8wBrFAKCqgE8AHAUxhLPKRnuZADN50NbiwDCTYsU5gArgFsARkwBOMAD6tSFQbUYsAKgAslTFsgDaYiQBoYl4jbsBdbcNYg8SgCaczh40xs-E0CjE2caUEhYAEswaKhovGJCdy8ALjcPb3MzOBsARhsAZkcbMyKbPJh80pgzQvhKx3CqWKhlXjxgFgBBJSU8OgAePQA+GABvKhgYWTwGIYBVUYAKaZmYYCTieS7yXjAMlYA3JOkmDL0bWM8mAA8MmQVlGw8BukuzRwBKJHHFqzrGZQAzRCB9ADmAH4MmQ6OtvhkJnUANIwWIwchMOh8LigiCODKLGAAX0EJJovGkYGACXA+AYDGIdAAsiBjkwVvJUp4MiksojMl5JutjFBpEowDBuVkAHRzBhrDYwFZKEAAd0uoQC6LAtweMCeiiUv0Q4xWN3uSEQyAADDAoQymaz2Uw9CAAEoa1Ua34ZNXq74I8mU6m06L0+bOtkc91e9U+zUwIJMQUpkUzMUSqVmABMNgD9VqhdzzRDVCAA)

Comment: I 'm wondering how do you track all these typescript issues?

Comment: @captain-yossarian a combination of GitHub search and just general interest in reading the issues.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the issues, but sometimes it is overhelming for me. Btw, could you pls take a look on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67914546/parameters-allows-wrapping-generic-function-but-infer-does-not/67923336#67923336?