# Dealing with Unwrapped Variadic Tuple Types

Tags: typescript, tuples, type-inference, variadic-tuple-types

Consider the following code:

```js
interface Wrap<Value> {
  pick(): Value
}

class WrapConstant<Value> implements Wrap<Value> {
  constructor(public readonly a: Value) { }
  pick(): Value { return this.a }
}

type Unwrap<Wrapped> = { [P in keyof Wrapped]: Wrapped[P] extends Wrap<infer Value> ? Value : never }

class WrapTuple<Tuple extends Wrap<unknown>[], Value = Unwrap<Tuple>> implements Wrap<Value> {
  readonly ts: Tuple
  constructor(...t: Tuple) { this.ts = t }

  pick(): Value { return this.ts.map(a => a.pick()) }                // fails to type check
}

type T1 = Unwrap<[WrapConstant<number>, WrapConstant<string>]>       // [number, string]

new WrapTuple(new WrapConstant(1), new WrapConstant("hello")).pick() // [1, "hello"]
```

Basically I'm unwrapping a tuple which I know to follow a certain shape (tuple of `Wrap<Values>`). The `pick()` function in `WrapTuple` is supposed to guarantee the return of the same shape of the unwrapped types (provided by `Unwrap<Tuple>`), although I get a type check error in that line. Questions:

1. Is this because `Unwrap<Tuple>` is not guaranteed to have the same shape due to the conditional type inference?
2. Is it possible to make it work without forcing a cast `as unknown as Value`?

---

**Update:** As commented by Linda, mapping a tuple does not result in a tuple. I tried merging my own declaration for map as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913193/how-to-use-array-map-with-tuples-in-typescript):

```js
interface Array<T> {
  map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, 
         thisArg?: any): { [K in keyof this]: U }
}
```

But this still requires the `map` to be asserted to `Value`:

```js
pick(): Value { return this.ts.map(a => a.pick()) as Value }
```

Comment: `.map` is always going to fail the typecheck because it returns an array of variable length instead of a tuple.

Comment: That's true, `map` will never return tuple, because it operates on mutable array

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Here is workaround:

```js
interface Wrap<Value> {
    pick(): Value
}

class WrapConstant<Value> implements Wrap<Value> {
    constructor(public readonly a: Value) { }
    pick(): Value { return this.a }
}

type Unwrap<Wrapped> = { [P in keyof Wrapped]: Wrapped[P] extends Wrap<infer Value> ? Value : never }

class WrapTuple<Tuple extends ReadonlyArray<Wrap<unknown>>> implements Wrap<unknown> {
    readonly ts: Tuple
    constructor(...ts: [...Tuple]) {
        this.ts = ts
    }

    pick(): Unwrap<[...Tuple]> // <-- added overload
    pick() {
        return this.ts.map(a => a.pick())
    }
}


const foo = new WrapTuple(new WrapConstant(1), new WrapConstant("hello")).pick() // [number, string]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOpTgBwDwDU4A2ArhAHzIDeAUMrcpsAgNYAUAlAFzL7ERUC%20VKggJwAzmLQZMAYQD2IMWDjg8hEuWABbTAQhaI4Seixre5anWQIFSqEQRg5UFpiIAjAo2RQIcACYKBACeyHBcPCRslMiCVgzM7BHqKBQ%20EGBEUCDIYAAWwGIAdHCxAkIi4sbSACpEuhDYNcgQAB6QIP6SAEp%20gSAhAIJQGMHYJjgqwaQzyNoNBkZSpkQgTCByAO4gFjR0vgFBoWBiXDV7tDaKYPaOzixFjydn0ZZWdPmFRSfIALy5YguZSBCVYnBqAG0QEQtO5oABdCHwyhAqxXJTIGByOR-XIFYonIpaLAsUq-chwIqg9hsVH7DJZHJYuRAwSCCq2MCY7G4kAQTbLTB1BosPkCibya4qMAsACMbAANMgxYLJUppSwAER5CAEAhyTVsNhUxhg5AAenNyBYEs50uw0Nh0HIAB9VXbVHZQABzUhsJFCIA)

**Looks like it works as expected with method overloading**

[Here](https://catchts.com/tuples#map) you can find more workarounds with tuples. This is my blog

Comment: Thanks for your workaround, but my problem is *exactly* for the case where I want to deal with tuples.

Comment: @HugoSerenoFerreira are you allowed to use `as` operator?

Comment: @HugoSerenoFerreira I made an update. Hope it is still relevant