# Ensuring type safety when using map function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following types

```
export type Player = 'x' | 'o'
export type GameFieldValue = null | Player;
export type Board = [
    [GameFieldValue, GameFieldValue, GameFieldValue],
    [GameFieldValue, GameFieldValue, GameFieldValue],
    [GameFieldValue, GameFieldValue, GameFieldValue],
]
```

Say I have an object of type Board

```
const board : Board = [
    ['x','x','o'],
    ['o','x','x'],
    ['x','x','x']
]
```

Now, I need a function that can invert all the values of the board (eg. `'x'` becomes `'o'` and the other way around)

```
const boardInverted : Board = [
    ['o','o','x'],
    ['x','o','o'],
    ['o','o','o']
]
```

The function I've come up with

```
function invertBoardValues(b:Board):Board {
    return b.map(row => row.map(val => val === 'x' ? 'o' : 'x'))
}
```

However, I get the error

```
Type '("x" | "o")[][]' is not assignable to type 'Board'.
Target requires 3 element(s) but source may have fewer.
```

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: TypeScript's typing for `Array.map` does not attempt to represent length preservation; see [microsoft/TypeScript#29841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29841) for details.  If you want to merge in your own overload for `map()` which does this, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913509/2887218) here, you can do so like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgrdbW).

Comment: Wow, thank you for this really detailed answer.

Comment: Oops, forgot to link to [the answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913509/2887218).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `as Board`:

```
function invertBoardValues(b:Board):Board {
    return b.map(row => row.map(val => val === 'x' ? 'o' : 'x')) as Board;
}
```