# Parameters allows wrapping generic function, but infer does not

Tags: typescript

Typescript throws an error when using inference for a function parameter when it doesn't for the utility type Parameters. Take the following example: [[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)]

```
interface Filter<T> {
    (inp: T): boolean;
}

// get parameter using Parameters
type InpParam<F extends Filter<never>> = Parameters<F>[0];
// get parameter using infer
type InpInfer<F extends Filter<never>> = F extends Filter<infer T> ? T : never;

// compiles fine
function wrapParam<F extends Filter<never>>(filt: F): Filter<InpParam<F>> {
    const wrapper = (inp: InpParam<F>): boolean => filt(inp);
    return wrapper;
}

function wrapInfer<F extends Filter<never>>(filt: F): Filter<InpInfer<F>> {
    const wrapper = (inp: InpInfer<F>): boolean => filt(inp);
    //                                                  ^^^
    // argument of type InpInfer<F> is not assignable to type never
    return wrapper;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure why InpParam is assignable to never, e.g. is inferred as never, when InpInfer isn't and is instead inferred as unknown. I could have to do with how they handle empty Parameters, but here Parameters actually returns the wrong thing, it returns undefined instead of unknown. (by wrong, I mean unknown is a more generic input parameter since function parameters are contravariant).

I'm curious about how to solve this for two reasons:

1. `undefined` is too narrow of a type, the actual type should be `unknown`. This presents a particular problem when intersecting with another type, because `unknown & T` => `T` but `undefined & {}` => `never`.
2. For complicated inputs types, writing the expression to extract a nested type can be complicated, hard to read, and brittle to changing object definitions. Infer, however, always works as long as the generics have the same semantics.

#### Notes

- I know that the specific wrappers in question can be written by making the wrapper generic in the input parameter, however that's not the case if I want to also preserve the type of the filter itself (these examples just don't illustrate that for clarity).
- I also know that the specific wrappers here don't do anything and so could be omitted.