# Can I used mapped tuple types for the juxt function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, ramda.js

juxt calls an array of functions to return an array of values. Docs: [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#juxt) [clojure](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/juxt)

I'm trying to type a data-first version of this without overrides, but I can't figure out how to [map the tuple of functions to their return values](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063). This is what I have:

```
type JuxtFn<T> = (x: T) => any
function juxt<T, Fs extends JuxtFn<T>[]>(
  x: T,
  fns: Fs,
): {[K in keyof Fs]: ReturnType<Fs[K]>} {
  return fns.map(fn => fn(x))
}
```

It complains (among other complaints)

```
Type 'Fs[K]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
```

Is this possible in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using function overload for this case:

```js
type JuxtFn<T> = (x: T) => any

function juxt<T, Fn extends JuxtFn<T>, Fns extends Fn[]>(
  x: T,
  fns: [...Fns],
): { [K in keyof Fns]: Fns[K] extends Fn ? ReturnType<Fns[K]> : never }
function juxt<T, Fs extends JuxtFn<T>[]>(
  x: T,
  fns: Fs,
) {
  return fns.map(fn => fn(x))
}

// [string[], Promise<number>]
const result = juxt(
  10,
  [(v: number) => ['s'], (v: number) => Promise.resolve(42)]
)
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wj4L8m)

I have added conditional type `Fns[K] extends Fn ? ReturnType<Fns[K]> : never`  just to assure TypeScript that `Fns[K]` is a function

You can find more information about infering return type of `[].map` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913193/how-to-use-array-map-with-tuples-in-typescript#answer-57913509). This was merged and then reverted.

In order to better understand this syntax `[...Fns]` please see documentation for [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types)

Comment: Wow! So is it required to use an overload here, or does that just make it cleaner? I'm not against the overload, I'm just curious.

Comment: I would say that most prefered way is to overload your function when you want to infer return type if function has an iterator. Also, you alway can write type assertion.

Comment: Thanks! I see that `[...Fns]` is required and it doesn't work to substitute `Fns`. Do you have a pointer for using spread/rest notation in the type definition? (Googling turns up lots of examples of rest arguments, but this is different, I think.)

Comment: Sorry, did not mention it. Google : typescript variadic tuple types

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the `ReturnType` isn't working.  Here's an alternative, however:

```
type JuxtFn<T> = (x: T) => any
function juxt<T, FS extends readonly JuxtFn<T>[]>(
  x: T,
  fns: FS,
) {
  return fns.map(fn => fn(x)) as unknown as { [K in keyof FS]: FS[K] extends (x:any)=>infer X ? X : never}
```

Full playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgrgD2AMQHYB4AqA%20KBeKACgQC4pMBKfXAQ1RACgAzOVAY2AEsB7VKAK0TAsAGijIAylAhIIqACYBnKACcINebwA2IWELRZsAbQC62QgyhRS5EZahNUispLtUA3vbXA4Kvo8UAOgBbGjBCR2oHVGIKKhplVgBrVG4Adz4EqHcoIwBpKE4%20JIgQbiZxCRMXCXyTaVkFZWISOhAKPGwipggVKAANKAB%20AagyVAgAN16AXwY5hjZeRWAoYO42JORWNmUCI3sW1DhggCNejuwEOysjk-OVS4RA4G4JYBUigHNCChuiUjHM4XTruOb1LJLJzABiLZarXQEQRIQgAZjE60223YigoQA).  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to have alternatives...