# TypeScript: Is it possible to map tuples in a typesafe way?

Tags: typescript

If I write this:

```js
declare function callbackFn<T>(entry: T): T extends string ? "string !" : "not string!";

const output= ([ "foo", 42 ] as const).map(callbackFn);
```

the type of `output` is `("string !" | "not string!")[]` is there any way to get it as `readonly [ "string !", "not string!" ]`?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696098/how-do-i-declare-a-read-only-array-tuple-in-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve with help of [function-overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

First of all, lets define `callbackFn`:

```js
type CallbackFn<T> = T extends string ? "string !" : "not string!";

function callbackFn<T>(entry: T): CallbackFn<T>
function callbackFn<T>(entry: T) {
  return typeof entry === 'string' ? "string !" : "not string!"
}
```

I have overloaded `callbackFn` and used `CallbackFn` type utility to infer return type.

Now, we need type utility for our mapping. Consider this:

```js
type MapUtility<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: CallbackFn<T[Prop]>
}

type Test1 = MapUtility<["foo", 42]> // ["string!", "not string!"]
```

Since all utils are set we can write our main function. Keep in mind, that it is not necessary to use `as const` to infer literal argument. You can use [variadic-tuple-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types):

```js
function map<
  Elem,
  Tuple extends Elem[]
>(tuple: [...Tuple]): MapUtility<Tuple>
function map(tuple: unknown[]) {
  return tuple.map(callbackFn)
}

// ["string !", "not string!"]
const output = map(["foo", 42])
```

Whole example:

```js
type CallbackFn<T> = T extends string ? "string !" : "not string!";

function callbackFn<T>(entry: T): CallbackFn<T>
function callbackFn<T>(entry: T) {
  return typeof entry === 'string' ? "string !" : "not string!"
}


type MapUtility<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: CallbackFn<T[Prop]>
}

type Test1 = MapUtility<["foo", 42]> // ["string!", "not string!"]
  
function map<
  Elem,
  Tuple extends Elem[]
>(tuple: [...Tuple]): MapUtility<Tuple>
function map(tuple: unknown[]) {
  return tuple.map(callbackFn)
}

// ["string !", "not string!"]
const output = map(["foo", 42])
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nlx4GN)

Please keep in mind that typescript does not preserve tuple length after `map`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913193/how-to-use-array-map-with-tuples-in-typescript#answer-57913509) answer.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231080/can-i-used-mapped-tuple-types-for-the-juxt-function/70243115#70243115) answer is related

P.S. If you are interested in function argument inference in TypeScript you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Comment: Thank you very much for the well detailed answer! Why is `Json` is relevant here, why can we just remove `extends Json` from `Elem extends Json`?

Comment: @JosephGarrone you are right, I have removed it. It is not relevant

Comment: Also thank you very much for the idea of using function overload for implementing generic function with complex return type. I was sick and tired of having to cast as any everything.

Comment: @JosephGarrone, no problem. Please keep in mind that function overloading dont gives you 100% of safety. They are bivariant, but at the same time I believe this is the cleanest way to do it in typescript

Comment: Yes yes of course but it doesn't provide any safety benefit but it is much cleaner like that!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with tuple types, I believe you have to avoid .map, try this instead:

```js
    const mapTuple = (tuple: [unknown, unknown]) => [callbackFn(tuple[0], callbackFn(tuple[1])] as const;
```

This way you still keep the tuple type as a return type.