# Array Map with Custom Types

Tags: typescript, array-map

I have the following types:

```
export type Point = [number, number];
export type LineType = [Point, Point];

export const hexPoint = (x: number, y: number, p: number): Point => {
  const [px, py] = coordinateToPoint(x, y);
  return [
    px + Math.cos((Math.PI * 2 * p) / 6) * size,
    py + Math.sin((Math.PI * 2 * p) / 6) * size,
  ];
};

const center = (point: Point): Point => {
  point[0] += w / 2;
  point[1] += h / 2;
  return point;
};

export const hexLineTop = (x: number, y: number): LineType => [
  hexPoint(x, y, 4),
  hexPoint(x, y, 5),
];

const constructHexagonalGrid = (points: [number, number][]): LineType[] => {
  let lines: LineType[] = [];
  points.forEach((point) => {
    lines.push(hexLineTop(...point).map(center));
  });
});
```

The line I'm struggling with is this one:

```
lines.push(hexLineTop(...point).map(center));
```

If I remove the `.map...` it all works OK:

```
lines.push(hexLineTop(...point));
```

But the line I'm using now (which modifies the location of the points) gives the error:

> Argument of type 'Point[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LineType'.
> Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2345)
> const center: (point: Point) => Point

I'm not sure of the syntax to make the map work. I've tried:

```
lines.push(hexLineTop(...point).map<LineType>(center));
```

and:

```
lines.push(hexLineTop(...point).map(center):LineType);
```

Comment: You may need to explicitly cast it, as apparently typescript does not care about array length when mapping. maybe an explicit `as LineType` would work?

Comment: fastest solution: `lines.push(hexLineTop(...point).map(center) as LineType);`

Comment: The `Array.prototype.map()` typings in TypeScript don't map tuples to tuples, so If you want this you have to use a type assertion or possibly merge in your own typings for `map()` (but that's not likely worth it).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913509/2887218) for more info.