# Typescript: How to preserve length information when using .map

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, tuples, type-inference

My current "working" approach is this:

```typescript
const generateMainOrientations = <T extends readonly string[]>(
  mainOrientationsNames: T
): { [Index in keyof T]: Orientation } => {
  const temp: Orientation[] = mainOrientationsNames.map(
    mainOrientationName => ({
      name: mainOrientationName,
      getYear(date) {
        return date.getFullYear()
      },
      getRecordContent: getMainOrientationRecordContent
    })
  )

  return temp as unknown as { [Index in keyof T]: Orientation }
}

const mainOrientations = generateMainOrientations([
  "One",
  "Two",
  "Three"
] as const)
```

However, I have to use `as unknown as { [Index in keyof T]: Orientation }`, which is not ideal, otherwise (even removing the type assertion from the `temp` variable) it will throw

```typescript
Type '{ name: string; getYear(date: any): any; getRecordContent: (values: number[]) => string[]; }[]' is not assignable to type '{ [Index in keyof T]: Orientation; }'.ts(2322)
```

Still, `{ name: string; getYear(date: any): any; getRecordContent: (values: number[]) => string[]; }` is the definition of `Orientation`

This shows that any length information is lost after map is used.

Is there a more organic way to achieve this, preferably without having to use type assertions at all, or at least without having to use `as unknown`. The objective would be to make mainOrientations a tuple of `Orientation` of the same length as the argument passed to `generateMainOrientations`, so `[Orientation, Orientation, Orientation]` in this case, (not `Orientation[]`).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJWBcczAPYjIDeAsAFDLIhwC2EAXMgM5gYgDmANOZexGAE0IcKAAoAJjgbIAIlICUjEAFcaAI2jcKyPmABKEBHijiAwgUjhRANzgAbZRCZLVGqAG0AuouatQ7L3IAX3JycUM7ERQYZRAEXAIdfgBZOFB0TGwEkAMjE3NwLDAbe0dnKldoLx8WNgDPULIjEBYkkGgpVPSMIpx8FuQAXmQAHgAVZAgAD0txJl86zmQx5QAHOxRp2fmxrwA+UR5kGjSQDN7spgA5WidGdwA6J5X1iAayHyJkdwBJEHCpshQMgANYQACeeBgyzWG08jHOWX6yCCQz2xCOzVakBoqwRPSRBC8Q2Op0RYD6BGutyYDxOq0O2koJ26mQp2RudDRyFEpCZlCot0YLLOBPZ-U5EC0AoFuiEIgkCgx-JlUH4yighEkkAeugAYso7HZ5WJ5EcZUFpTKkvpDMYzBYioxdF1RWzKTk7flHeBzSizdoA0c1WANYQcatkHB5rEQSA8AB3QjR4jfP4AoGEMGQ6EvOH493ZFHBRpYsCk1kXfrzYZ8dpQTpksUepiidxHABEqHaHatHbGCbwvc7YwAFmqIB3yN4gA)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what your expected outcome/type is. Are you wanting your output type to be a generic array of Orientations? Or do you want the type to reflect the exact number of Orientations i.e. `[Orientations, Orientations, Orientations]`. If so - why?

Comment: Please provide reproducible example. Btw, there is not need to use `as const` assertion. Use variadic tuple types: `const generateMainOrientations = <T extends string,Tuple extends T[]>(
    mainOrientationsNames: [...Tuple]
)`

Comment: @DaneBrouwer Yes. I want the type of the output to be a tuple of `Orientation` of the same length as the argument (`[Orientation, Orientation, Orientation]` in this case), not a generic array (so no `Orientation[]`).

Comment: @captain-yossarian I updated the original question with a link to a playground. Also, thanks for the variadic tuples advice, I completely forgot about them.

Comment: @Aplietexe Why would you want it as a tuple as opposed to a typed array. Obviously all these types are compile time, so you should still be coding as if you didn't know the exact length regardless. Is there value in maintaining a tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to overload your function:

```js
interface Orientation {
  name: string,
  getYear(date: Date): number,
  getRecordContent(values: number[]): string[]
}

declare function getMainOrientationRecordContent(values: number[]): string[]

function generateMainOrientations<T extends string, Tuple extends T[]>(
  mainOrientationsNames: [...Tuple]
): { [Index in keyof Tuple]: Orientation }
function generateMainOrientations(
  mainOrientationsNames: string[]
) {
  return mainOrientationsNames.map(
    mainOrientationName => ({
      name: mainOrientationName,
      getYear: (date: Date) => date.getFullYear(),
      getRecordContent: getMainOrientationRecordContent
    })
  )
}

// [Orientation, Orientation, Orientation]
const mainOrientations = generateMainOrientations([
  "One",
  "Two",
  "Three"
])
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WybVAw)

Please keep in mind, that once you used `Array.prototype.map` , typescript don't preserve the length of the result. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913193/how-to-use-array-map-with-tuples-in-typescript) you can find why.

hence, you have **only** two options: overloading and type assertion.

You can do even better if you make `name` property parametrized :

```js
interface Orientation<Name extends string> {
  name: Name,
  getYear(date: Date): number,
  getRecordContent(values: number[]): string[]
}

declare function getMainOrientationRecordContent(values: number[]): string[]

function generateMainOrientations<T extends string, Tuple extends T[]>(
  mainOrientationsNames: [...Tuple]
): { [Index in keyof Tuple]: Orientation<Tuple[Index] & string> }
function generateMainOrientations(
  mainOrientationsNames: string[]
) {
  return mainOrientationsNames.map<Orientation<string>>(
    name => ({
      name,
      getYear: (date) => date.getFullYear(),
      getRecordContent: getMainOrientationRecordContent
    })
  )
}

// [Orientation<"One">, Orientation<"Two">, Orientation<"Three">]
const mainOrientations = generateMainOrientations([
  "One",
  "Two",
  "Three"
])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `temp as any`

```
const generateMainOrientations = <T extends readonly string[]>(
  mainOrientationsNames: T
): { [Index in keyof T]: Orientation } => {
  const temp = mainOrientationsNames.map((mainOrientationName) => ({
    name: mainOrientationName,
    getYear(date: Date) {
      return date.getFullYear();
    },
    getRecordContent: getMainOrientationRecordContent
  }));

  return temp as any;
};
```

Comment: This still doesn't preserve length information. Here, the return value of `generateMainOrientations` is `Orientation[]`, but the idea would be for it to be a tuple of the same length as the argument it was called with (so `[Orientation, Orientation, Orientation]`).